# why file extenssions are created?

Tags: file-extension

my friends
I have a question about why file extensions are created?
I found a quote on Wikipedia

"They are commonly used to imply information about the way data might be stored in the file"

what does it mean?

Comment: Why are we taught to identify the taste of a food item, before even trying it? i.e. salty, spicy, sweet, tangy? or hot/cold ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File extension is an identifier which tell the operating system what kind of data and file type they are working with and what associated program opens the file.

if u have an .apk extension file, system can easily recognize it as an application file. If it is an mp4, means it's some kind of multimedia file and can be operated with multimedia applications.

They are commonly used to imply information about the way data might be stored in the file. A normal text editor uses `.txt` as extension when an html uses extension `.html` These two files stores data differently.

Comment: thank you... but what do you mean "these two files stores data differently"?

Comment: i mean what's diffrence between stored data in HTML file versus txt file?

Comment: if you save an HTML code as a plain text file and open it in a browser, it just shows the content exactly like that (html tags and other syntaxes) . Because according to the browser it's just a plain text. It displays the tags just like a text.

But the same file is saved as an HTML file, the browser consider the HTML tags and it syntaxes and display only the content inside the tags, which means the output.